# codeigniter array

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I grab this data and increment it in Codeigniter?

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$_GET[id]]++;
```

Comment: i hope this link help http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html :retrive $value = $this->session->userdata('entery'); then set  $this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');

Comment: CodeIgniter also has a shopping cart class - which might help you achieve what it is you are trying to do. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html

Answer (score 3):

because CI destroys the $_GET array, you *can* do this

`$_SESSION['cart'][$this->uri->segment(3)]++;`

where 3 is the URL segment of the ID. But I would look in to the shopping cart class as recommended by Malachi.

from the docs ~

```
$data = array(
               'rowid' => 'b99ccdf16028f015540f341130b6d8ec',
               'qty'   => 3
            );

$this->cart->update($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's frowned upon, but if you really want to use the $_GET var you can always do the following:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
```

I would stick with using URI segments as shown by Ross or have the 'id' supplied as a parameter in the controller function.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this...

> $cart = $this->session->userdata('cart');
>   $cart[$this->uri->segment(3)];

Answer (score 0):

$this->input->get() is no longer messed with, so GET away.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way.

By passing variable in your controller function, Your controller function will look like this

```
function my_function($id='')
{
    //Your code goes here
    $my_cart = $this->session->userdata('cart');
    $my_data = $my_cart[$id];

}
```